# Batch Script Specifics

Tags: batch-file

In JavaScript you can use a var assignment to save a variable and then call upon it later on in the code, and you can also prompt the user to enter in some script and then have that value saved to a variable to be used in calculations. Is that possible in Batch Script? Like, can I have my user put in a value during my script and then use that value in a conditional statement to continue on the script? For example,

```
echo.
echo Simplify the following equation into it's most basic form. 
echo.
echo "-2X + 5 + 10X - 9"
::USER INPUT IS NEEDED HERE TO BE SAVED AND THEN UTILIZED
If ( usersInput === " -8x - 4 " ) 

echo You got it right! 
goto continued 

Else ( goto end )
```

Am I thinking this through correctly? Is there a different approach to this that I should be taking?

Comment: Well for a start the correct response would be `8X - 4` not `-8x - 4`.

Comment: Incidentally, you already know how to ask questions, accept responses as variables and make comparisons using the correct syntax. _(You did so in your last question two days ago)._

Comment: IMO comparing such user input would require strict formality and even then `10X`would be equivalent to `X*10` so how would you take this into account?

Comment: Thank you guys, I sometimes forget what I really do know. I'm just trying to adjust to the new language. Sorry for the almost repetitive questions.

Comment: Would the If-Else loop work in that fashion?? and then just have the continued block down just to have it go on to the next question? And would I have to name them differently or would it manage to follow the script just straight down the page following the outline??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo(
echo Simplify the following equation into it's most basic form. 
echo(
echo "-2X + 5 + 10X - 9" 

set /p "usersInput=Enter answer: "


If /I "%usersInput%" == "8x - 4" (
    echo You got it right! 
    goto continued 
) Else (
    goto end
)
```

Notes:

- `echo(` is much faster and safer than  `echo.`
- `set /p` prompts the user
- enclose variable name with %
- `/I` makes the if statement case-insensitive
- Please do `if /?` to see the correct `if` syntax

#### By the way, the correct answer is `8x - 4`(or `8x-4`), as @Compo said...